# Browsing from IIS my ASP.NET web app gets "error 404 - file or directory not found" when I publish it to Windows Server 2016 on AWS

Tags: asp.net, windows, visual-studio, iis

I built this ASP.NET web app project with Visual Studio 2017.
Same project browses locally and by Internet on my old Azure server, just not on new AWS EC2 Windows Server 2016.

I set projects security permissions to "Everyone" full access.

project start file is Default.aspx and that's what is set in IIS > my site > defaults

Comment: any information from IIS log or application log ?

Comment: Maybe you set a wrong site binding, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Answer (score 0):

make sure the application pool has permissions to the site folders.  use the application pool name as the user name when setting the permissions.